# An error has occurred The application failed to start (exited with code 1). Loading required package: carData Error in value[[3L]](cond) :

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make my shiny app public, so I try to use the Shinyapps.io. But I got this error which avoids me to complete the final step. How can I solve such a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error is quite informative, the `server` doesn't exist. This usually happens when brackets haven't been closed properly. Make sure your app.R follows this structure:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # ui code goes here
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # server code goes here
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you have ui.R, server.R make sure you also have either an app.R or global.R that sources both ui.R and server.R and be sure to put them all in the same location.

Comment: I have checked my code. I think the brackets are closed because my code can properly run on my local webpage.

Comment: Hard to say exactly what causes this. it might be something inside your server that only exists on your pc and not on shiny server, hence creating the server fails. Have a look at the logs, which you can access on your dashboard https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/208120507/shinyappsLog.png